# Name of Current Service in Google App Engine (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Using the Google App Engine Python API is there a way to access the name of the currently running service --i.e., the service name specified in your `app.yaml` file with `service: foobar`?

Module `google.appengine.api.app_identity` provide functions to get application id, default version hostname and service account name but none for service name.

I checked the overview of module here [App Identity Python API Overview](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/appidentity/) and the API reference here [google.appengine.api.app_identity.app_identity module](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.app_identity.app_identity)

I need the service name to build the full URL of current service:  `http://service-name.application-id.appspot.com/some/url/path/`

The call to `get_default_version_hostname` returns only `application-id.appspot.com` without he service name component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Services used to be called modules not long ago (you can still find such references in the documentation, not all of it was updated).

You're probably looking for `google.appengine.api.modules.modules.get_current_module_name()`.

From [`google.appengine.api.modules.modules`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.modules.modules):

> **google.appengine.api.modules.modules.get_current_module_name()**
>
> [source](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/api/modules/modules#get_current_module_name)
>
> Returns the module name of the current instance.
>
> If this is version “v1” of module “module5” for app “my-app”, this
>   function will return “module5”.